# Unserialize large data not working in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, array, unserialize

I've created a custom module on my Magento 1.9.4.0 website, which creates a CSV feed file with all products and you can add dynamically what product attributes to display in the file. Something like in the image below.

[image: serialized]

The field is created like this:

```
<product_attributes translate="label comment">
    <label>Product Attributes</label>
    <frontend_model>company_fullfeed/adminhtml_system_config_form_field_attributes</frontend_model>
    <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_serialized_array</backend_model>
    <sort_order>50</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    <comment>Select product attributes that will be added to feed.</comment>
</product_attributes>
```

and all the attributes are saving in **core_config_data** as a serialized string.

The module works perfect, the file is created with products. The problem appears when I add more than 59 attributes, after that the file it is not generated. The problem seems to be from the unserialize method:

```
$mapValues = Mage::helper('core/unserializeArray')->unserialize($conf);
```

where `$conf` is the serialized array.

Does anyone know if there is a problem with Magento unserializing larger arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more detailed code debugging I just found out that the problem in my case is not about the unserialize method, that still works fine. The problem is that my module creates a very very big query with a lot of JOINs in it and I got this MySql error:

> Too many tables; MySQL can only use 61 tables in a join

So, my solution was to divide the query in more queries and now everything works perfect.